# GoJS: How do I get node data by searching a node in the diagram?

Tags: html, gojs

Starting with login user data, I would like to see only the sub diagram.

```
function showLocalOnFullClick() {

    var node = myDiagram.selection.first();

    if (node !== null) {

        myDiagram.scrollToRect(node.actualBounds);


        var model = new go.TreeModel();

        var nearby = node.findTreeParts(); // three levels of the (sub)tree

        nearby.each(function(n) {
            if (n instanceof go.Node) model.addNodeData(n.data);
        });
        myDiagram.model = model;

        var selectedLocal = myDiagram.findPartForKey(node.data.key);
        if (selectedLocal !== null) selectedLocal.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way than `var node = myDiagram.selection.first();`?

I want Get data from search or key

- `findNodesByExample`
- `findNodeForData`
- `findNodeDataForKey`